# Running footer not visible on first page

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I am using below XSLT to generate report with running footer, but the first page of ther report doesn't have the running footer, please advice what needs to be changed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts">
  <xsl:template match="/" >
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <!-- defines the layout master -->
      <fo:layout-master-set >
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="first"
        page-height="290mm" page-width="210mm" margin-top="0mm" margin-bottom="10mm" margin-left="20mm" margin-right="0mm">
          <fo:region-body margin-top="15mm" margin-bottom="15mm"/>
          <fo:region-after extent="10mm" region-name="footer-normal"></fo:region-after>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="first">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="footer-normal">
          <fo:block text-align="center" font-size="7pt" font-style="italic" font-family="sans-serif">

              <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="chapter"/>
              PAGE <fo:page-number/> of
              <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="last-page"/>

           </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <xsl:for-each select="ArrayOfRoomReportBE/RoomReportBE" >
            <xsl:variable name="RoomNo_node" select=".//RoomNumber"/>
            <fo:marker marker-class-name="chapter" font-size="7pt" font-style="italic"
                            font-family="sans-serif">
              <xsl:value-of select="$RoomNo_node"/>
            </fo:marker>
            <!-- Dispaly datat -->  
          </xsl:for-each>
          <fo:block id="last-page"/>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input document used is as follows

```
<ArrayOfRoomReportBE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <RoomReportBE>
    <Id>0</Id>
    <RoomNumber>TestCap1</RoomNumber>
    <RoomName>TestCap1</RoomName>
    <Comment>Testing a bit</Comment>
    <GeneralAspect>
      <GeneralAttributeTitle>
        <ReferenceLink>Reference Link</ReferenceLink>
        <Notes>General Notes</Notes>
        <GeneralHeader>General</GeneralHeader>
        <MaxCO2>Max CO2</MaxCO2>
        <DimensionHeader>Dimension</DimensionHeader>
        <NetAreaTitle>Net area</NetAreaTitle>
        <ClimateHeader>Climate</ClimateHeader>
        <MinTempTitle>Min Temperature</MinTempTitle>
        <MaxTempTitle>Max Temperature </MaxTempTitle>
        <OpenHoursTitle>Open hours</OpenHoursTitle>
        <NonOpenHoursTitle>Non open hours</NonOpenHoursTitle>
        <AcousticsHeader>Acoustics</AcousticsHeader>
        <MaxInstallationNoiseTitle>Max installation noise</MaxInstallationNoiseTitle>
        <SoundInsulationTitle>Sound insulation</SoundInsulationTitle>
        <WorkplacesOccupancyHeader>Occupancy/Workplaces</WorkplacesOccupancyHeader>
        <OccupancyTitle>Occupancy</OccupancyTitle>
        <NoOfWorkspaceTitle>Number of workplaces</NoOfWorkspaceTitle>
        <TypeOfWorkspaceTitle>Type of workplaces</TypeOfWorkspaceTitle>
      </GeneralAttributeTitle>
      <AspectAttributeItems>
        <GeneralAttributeItemBE>
          <GeneralNoOfWorkplaces />
          <GeneralDimensionNetArea>12</GeneralDimensionNetArea>
          <GeneralClimateMinTempOpen>-19°C</GeneralClimateMinTempOpen>
          <GeneralClimateMinTempNonOpen>-15°C</GeneralClimateMinTempNonOpen>
          <GeneralClimateMaxTempOpen>-6°C</GeneralClimateMaxTempOpen>
          <GeneralClimateMaxTempNonOpen>-11°C</GeneralClimateMaxTempNonOpen>
          <Notes />
          <ReferenceLink />
        </GeneralAttributeItemBE>
      </AspectAttributeItems>
    </GeneralAspect>
    <FloorAspect>
      <FloorAttributeTitle>
        <Description>Description</Description>
        <ReferenceLink>Reference Link</ReferenceLink>
        <Notes>General Notes</Notes>
        <FloorFinishTitle>Floor Finish</FloorFinishTitle>
        <FloorHeader>Floor</FloorHeader>
        <FloorSubstractTitle>Floor Substrate</FloorSubstractTitle>
        <FloorColorTitle>Floor Colour</FloorColorTitle>
        <FloorSkirtingTitle>Skirting</FloorSkirtingTitle>
      </FloorAttributeTitle>
      <AspectAttributeItems>
        <FloorAttributeItemBE>
          <Description />
          <Notes />
          <ReferenceLink />
        </FloorAttributeItemBE>
        <FloorAttributeItemBE>
          <FloorSubstract>Block pavement</FloorSubstract>
          <FloorColor>Medium grey</FloorColor>
          <FloorSkirting>N/A</FloorSkirting>
          <FloorFinish>Ceramic tiles textured</FloorFinish>
          <Description>test</Description>
          <Notes />
          <ReferenceLink />
        </FloorAttributeItemBE>
      </AspectAttributeItems>
    </FloorAspect>
    <WallAspect>
      <WallAttributeTitle>
        <Description>Description</Description>
        <ReferenceLink>Reference Link</ReferenceLink>
        <Notes>General Notes</Notes>
        <WallHeader>Wall</WallHeader>
        <WallNameTitle>Wall</WallNameTitle>
        <WallFinishTitle>Wall finish</WallFinishTitle>
        <WallColorTitle>Wall Colour</WallColorTitle>
      </WallAttributeTitle>
      <AspectAttributeItems>
        <WallAttributeItemBE>
          <WallName>Facade</WallName>
          <WallFinish>Special</WallFinish>
          <WallColor>TestValue</WallColor>
          <Description>test</Description>
          <Notes />
          <ReferenceLink>test</ReferenceLink>
        </WallAttributeItemBE>
      </AspectAttributeItems>
    </WallAspect>
    <CeilingAspect>
      <CeilingAttributeTitle>
        <ReferenceLink>Reference Link</ReferenceLink>
        <Notes>General Notes</Notes>
        <AcousticsTitle>Acoustics</AcousticsTitle>
        <CeilingInsertsTitle>Inserts</CeilingInsertsTitle>
        <CeilingHeightTitle>Ceiling height</CeilingHeightTitle>
        <CeilingHeader>Ceiling</CeilingHeader>
        <CeilingSuspendedTitle>Suspended Ceiling</CeilingSuspendedTitle>
        <CeilingRoomAcousticsTitle>Room acoustics</CeilingRoomAcousticsTitle>
        <CeilingCoverageTitle>Coverage</CeilingCoverageTitle>
        <CeilingTypeTitle>Type</CeilingTypeTitle>
        <CeilingOthersTitle>Other</CeilingOthersTitle>
      </CeilingAttributeTitle>
      <AspectAttributeItems>
        <CeilingAttributeItemBE>
          <Notes />
          <ReferenceLink />
        </CeilingAttributeItemBE>
      </AspectAttributeItems>
    </CeilingAspect>
    <EquipmentAspect>
      <EquipmentAttributeTitle>
        <ReferenceLink>Reference Link</ReferenceLink>
        <Notes>General Notes</Notes>
        <EquipmentHeader>Equipment</EquipmentHeader>
        <EquipmentNameTitle>Equipment</EquipmentNameTitle>
        <EquipmentQuantityTitle>Quantity</EquipmentQuantityTitle>
        <EquipmentConnectionsTitle>Connections</EquipmentConnectionsTitle>
        <Description>Description</Description>
      </EquipmentAttributeTitle>
      <AspectAttributeItems>
        <EquipmentAttributeItemBE>
          <EquipmentName>-</EquipmentName>
          <EquipmentQuantity>100</EquipmentQuantity>
          <EquipmentConnections>220V</EquipmentConnections>
          <Description>test2</Description>
          <Notes />
          <ReferenceLink />
        </EquipmentAttributeItemBE>
      </AspectAttributeItems>
    </EquipmentAspect>
  </RoomReportBE>
  <RoomReportBE>
  </RoomReportBE>
</ArrayOfRoomReportBE>
```

Comment: Could you please provide your input XML to check for the transformation

Comment: i have added input document

Comment: Issue resolved .. added farmer after fo:block              <fo:block break-before='page' font-size="3mm" font-family="sans-serif">
 <fo:marker marker-class-name="roomInfo" font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif">
      <xsl:value-of select="$RoomNo_node"/>
      <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" leader-length="3px"></fo:leader>
       <xsl:value-of select="$RoomName_node"/>
</fo:marker>

Answer (score 0):

Please change two things: first, `<fo:region-after extent="10mm" region-name="footer-normal">` to `<fo:region-after extent="10mm">`. And second, change `<fo:static-content flow-name="footer-normal">` to `<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">.`

Comment: Hi Navin, i tried your solution but still first page doesn't contain the required running footer whereas other pages are having proper running footer. It's bit stange why only first page is not having running footer

Comment: Have you created any other page sequence instead of 'first'?